# How to Update child stateful widget on update parent stateful widget

Tags: flutter, state-management, flutter-widget, statefulwidget

When ever update parent stateful widget it should also update child stateful widget.When ever I refresh Parent stateful widget not updating child stateful widget. Any one know how can I update both stateful widget when update parent stateful widget?

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: BLoC design pattern will help you easily, learn more at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Comment: try `provider` package

Answer (score 0):

You should get into StateManagement, also you can try  passing `setState` in the constructor form parent to child widget